# Advice on how to solve a constrained KL Divergence problem between a Dirichlet and a Logistic Normal

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler, dirichlet-distribution

I would like some advice or path to follow to solve the following problem.

Consider a random variable $Y$ that follows a Dirichlet distribution $Y \sim Dir(\alpha)$. Let $X$ be a member of the Logistic Normal family of distributions, with density given by

$$ f_X( \mathbf{x}; \boldsymbol{\mu} , \boldsymbol{\Sigma} ) = \frac{1}{ | (2 \pi)^{D-1} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} |^\frac{1}{2} } \, \frac{1}{ \prod\limits_{i=1}^D x_i } \, e^{- \frac{1}{2} \left\{ \log \left( \frac{ \mathbf{x}_{-D} }{ x_D } \right) - \boldsymbol{\mu} \right\}^\top \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \left\{ \log \left( \frac{ \mathbf{x}_{-D} }{ x_D } \right) - \boldsymbol{\mu} \right\} } \ \ , \ \  \mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{S}^D $$

where $f{x}_{-D}$ denotes a vector of the first (D-1) components of $f(x)$ and $\mathcal{S}^D$ denotes the simplex of D-dimensional probability vectors. The function $\log(\cdot)$ is applied elementwise.

I would like to minimize the KL divergence between $Y$ and a member of the logistic normal distribution, with the constraint that the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is diagonal.

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution) and [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2335470) by Aitchison present the result when there is no constraint on $\Sigma$. A guide on how to find the analytical solution would be very nice but a numerical solution also works for me.

Thank you.